# Regarding On Key Press = Enter in textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
Game Name <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="game_name" onblur="$('#weight_id_1').focus();">
```

I have the code above, if I click elsewhere, it will set focus to weight_id_1

However I would like to actually inline with the text field to actually focus on weight_id_1 on keypress = enter

How do I achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking. Are you saying when a person hits enter in the textbox, you want to focus another element?

Comment: May be use a javascript function get the keycode of the pressed keys, if it matches the Enter keycode then write `$('#weight_id_1').focus();`. There are many ready-made codes how to get the keycode while typing in a text box. Search for it.

Answer (score 1):

@clement's answer is perfectly right; however, a small improvement would be to use the `keyup` event because it fires only once rather than many times for as long as the key is depressed. also, if this is in a form, you should prevent default so it's not submitted

```
$('#text_field').on('keyup', function(e) { // fires only once per keypress
    e.preventDefault();
    e.which == 13 && $('#weight_id_1').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of a jQuery keypress event :

```
$( "#your_text_field" ).keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 13 ) { //13 is for enter
    $('#weight_id_1').focus();
  }      
});
```